# Lithium battery basics

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion

I have a few things that I don't get about this battery .

1. In our product, when we connect the `lithium battery 3.7V` charged, things work, but when it's discharged, we can see that the voltage is 0! It's not around 2-3V but goes to 0, why does that happen?
2. How do you know that the battery you hold in your hands is fully charged? The fact that the voltage is around 4.2V means it's in full capacity (from current perspective)?
3. Charging with `max1555`, does it take care of all charging issues?
4. How long must such a battery be charged? For example, `850mAh ,3.7V`, how long do you charge it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You have probably over-discharged the battery and the internal protection circuit has disconnected it. Some internal disconnects will automatically reconnect when you recharge the battery.

2) Probably true provided the battery is not connected to anything (not being charged or discharged)

3) Integrated solutions such as the MAX555 should do pretty much what you need

4) The charge time depends upon the current you supply to the battery and its capacity.  The MAX555 charges at ~280mA if you supply it with 5V.  This would take about 3 hours to supply the 850mAh capacity of the battery.  It will slow down as the battery becomes charged so maybe an extra hour for 4 hours total. At lower currents the time will be proportionately longer.